# Vue installing but -v and create not working

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to install vue, it says it has added vue package but when I do  `npm i -g @vue/cli` it gives a long list of error which ends with

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall chmod npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/atob/bin/atob.js'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/ammar/.npm/_logs/2019-01-13T18_54_35_766Z-debug.log

I am using macOS Mojave

Comment: You can try this: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally - please let us know if it helps.

Comment: @BeniaminH I tried install npm as told in the docs but I got long log of error.

Comment: You can paste it here or to pastebin - I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using your sudo credentials:

```
sudo npm i -g @vue/cli
```